# How to validate WooCommerce checkout form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce the checkout form (Town/City) not validating with this code.

```php
// Check if Ship to a different address is set, if it's set then validate shipping fields.
if (!empty($ship_to_different_address)) {
    if (empty(trim($billing_city)) || !ctype_alpha($billing_city)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Shipping First Name</strong>.'), 'error');
    }
    if (empty(trim($shipping_city)) || !ctype_alpha($shipping_city)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Shipping Last Name</strong>.'), 'error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you added this code.?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the trick...

```
function so_61559494_validate_checkout() {

    if( ! empty( $_POST['ship_to_different_address'] ) ) {

        $billing_city = ! empty( $_POST['billing_city'] ) ? trim( $_POST['billing_city'] ) : '';

        if (  empty( $billing_city ) || ! ctype_alpha( $billing_city ) ) {
            $notice = __('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Billing City</strong>.', 'your-text-domain' );
            throw new Exception( $notice );
        }

        $shiping_city = ! empty( $_POST['shiping_city'] ) ? trim( $_POST['shiping_city'] ) : '';

        if ( empty( $shipping_city ) || ! ctype_alpha( $shipping_city ) ) {
            $notice = __('Only alphabets are alowed in <strong>Shipping City</strong>.', 'your-text-domain' );
            throw new Exception( $notice );
        }

    }

} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'so_61559494_validate_checkout' );
```

It's entirely untested though, so use with caution.